# Increase performance of SELECT * FROM # ORDER BY # ASC LIMIT # OFFSET #;

Tags: sql, performance, jpa, hsqldb

Basically, I want to do effective and fast lazy loading sorted list on a web page with HSQLDB.
My current SQL query ineffective and slow:

```
SELECT o FROM Human AS o ORDER BY o.firstName ASC LIMIT 500k OFFSET 50;
```

Could I increase performance of it?

Domain Object:

```
@RooJpaActiveRecord
public class Human {
    @NotNull
    @Column(name="firstName")
    String firstName;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name="lastName")
    String lastName;
}
```

SQL table:

```
Id, firstName, lastName, Version
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an index on the `firstName` column and you are ready to go (if you are gonna sort only/first by firstName). Of course this depends on your database. For MySQL see [this page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/order-by-optimization.html).

Comment: yes I need to sort by firstName and lastName as well. I will add indexes to these fields, that's it? Could you provide an example or link to tutorial?

Comment: there are often use the phrase 'ORDER BY RAND()'. Do you know what does it mean?

Comment: Yes, that is used for random sorting (each query will return a differing sorting). RAND() is a function in MySQL.